# How to exit from a ROS2 lifecycle launch script?

Tags: ros, ros2, state

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

is there a way to interrupt the execution of a ROS2 launch script?

In my case I have a lifecycle node managed by a lifecycle launch script. I would like to stop the execution of the script if the lifecycle node reaches the finalized state:

```
[...]

node_finalized_state_handler = RegisterEventHandler(
        OnStateTransition(
            target_lifecycle_node = node,
            goal_state = 'finalized',
            entities = [
                # Log
                LogInfo( msg = "'NODE' reached the 'FINALIZED' state." ),
                ***** INSERT SOMETHING HERE TO EXIT??? *****
            ],
        )
    )

[...]

# Add the actions to the launch description.
# The order they are added reflects the order in which they will be executed.
ld.add_action( node_inactive_from_unconfigured_state_handler )
ld.add_action( node_inactive_from_active_state_handler )
ld.add_action( node_active_state_handler )
ld.add_action( node_finalized_state_handler )
ld.add_action( node )
ld.add_action( node_configure_trans_event)

return ld
```

I cannot find a solution...

Thank you
Walter

**Update:**
I found the `OpaqueFunction` action and it seems that I can use it to call `sys.exit`, but the script still remains active because the Node is still running and "waiting" in the `finalized` state.
So before using `sys.kill` I need to kill the running Node... how?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/307818/how-to-exit-from-a-ros2-lifecycle-launch-script?/) by [Myzhar](https://answers.ros.org/users/455/myzhar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 541 on 2018-11-07

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would recommend you emit the shutdown event, e.g.:

https://github.com/ros2/launch/blob/a89671962220c8691ea4f128717bca599c711cda/launch/examples/launch_counters.py#L96-L98

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2018-11-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Myzhar](https://answers.ros.org/users/455/myzhar/) on 2018-11-09**:
Good, it works. Thank you :)